# Error al usar length en Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Estoy usando length en el grantResult en una condicional, pero me bota error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La clase `IntArray` no cuenta con la propiedad `length` por lo que debes utilizar `size` para obtener el número de elementos en el arreglo. Puedes revisar más información sobre la clase en el siguiente enlace: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int-array/index.html

Answer (score 0):

La clase `IntArray` no cuenta con la propiedad `length` por lo que debes utilizar `size` para obtener el número de elementos en el arreglo.

Puedes revisar más información sobre la clase en el siguiente enlace:

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int-array/index.html